# Three js glTF imported model's material contains unexpected field "format"

Tags: three.js

After importing a textureless model from a glTF file using GLTFLoader, the object's material contains a field named "format". Without removing this field, some changes to the material are not applied.

E.g. the following code example:

```
material.opacity = 0.5
material.transparent = true
```

requires the additional cleanup:

```
delete material.format
material.needsUpdate = true
```

In the documentation, "format" appears to be a property of textures and not of materials, thus I do not understand the meaning of it when the imported model contains no textures. Is this a problem with the glTF file or with threeJS? or Am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `material.format` was a temporary change in a few versions of three.js, and has been removed in three.js r137. I believe it existed only for versions r132–r136, but those versions do require the additional cleanup you mention, in order to enable alpha blending transparency on the material.